# Workflow stuck on "Wait for field to equal value" step - Sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint, workflow, wait

I have a TaskList with about 20 columns and i am trying to achieve the following process using workflow:

1. A user creates a task filling fields 1, 2, 3
2. Department manager receives a notification that new task has been
       created and assigns the engineer
3. Assigned Eng receives notification.

I seems to have problem with point 3. So far i tried 2 things:

- Enabling email notification for "Assigned to:" (default column) which
  seems to work only if the "Assigned to:" filed is filled when the
  task is created, not when task is modified.
- I introduced new column called "Eng assigned" which is a check box
  with Yes/No values.  When the manager has to assign the Eng, he fills
  "Assigned to:" and ticks "Eng assigned" filed. Unfortunately this
  doesn't work either and workflow gets stuck on the  Wait step. This
  is my workflow:

Wait for Eng Assigned to equal Yes

If Current Item:Eng Assigned equals Yes

Email CurrentItem:Assigned to:

I also tried without IF XXX but the result is the same... Can you please advise?

Thank you in advance!